# Regex no matches with linux find

Tags: regex, find

I am at a loss what is making this simple command not return any matches. I get zero results in all variations below:

```
find . -type d -regex '.+ [0-9]{4}' -print | wc -c;
find * -type d -regex '.+[0-9]{4}' -print | wc -c;
find * -type d -regex '.+[0-9]' -print | wc -c;
find . -type d -regex '[0-9]' -print | wc -c;
```

If I use '.+' regex then I get all results as expected. Directories are name in this pattern: [1 or more words] [4 digits]. I want to match any directory ending in a year and print it. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/63891484/11329890 working for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-regextype` option with an extended regex type e.g.:

```
find . -type d -regextype egrep -regex '.+-[0-9]{4}$
```

Note that default value of `-regextype` is `emacs`

Answer (score 0):

Use `-regextype 'posix-extended'` with your regex:

```
find . -type d -regextype 'posix-extended' -regex '.*[0-9]{4}' -print | wc -c
```

This expression will returns all directories ending in four digits.